# onCreatePresentation of CastRemoteDisplayLocalService never called

Tags: android, chromecast

I created a CastRemoteDisplayLocalService descendant following the official docs.

OnCreate is called, onCreatePresentation never. What can be the reason behind this?

I used this code as an example: https://github.com/pasha656/Chromecast/tree/master/CastDisplay I had different package names but the same app ID - maybe this can be a problem. I tried to search the official docs whether app IDs and packages are linked together - no success, no info so far.

Answer (score 3):

The above referred [project](https://github.com/pasha656/Chromecast/tree/master/CastDisplay) and [my project](https://github.com/syatam/Cast-Remote-Display) are calling onCreatePresentation() for me. I am not sure what are you missing

I would recommend you to follow the below steps and see if you can figure out something

1. Download this project : https://github.com/syatam/Cast-Remote-Display
2. Import to Android Studio and install it on Android mobile
3. App launches => Click on PLAY and select the chromecast device
4. When the app is connected with chromecast device, you should see onCreatePresentation() is being called in your logcat messages.

Share me your sample project if you are unable to figure out. I can take a look at it.

Comment: After searching a lot I finally found this github project that actually works. If you are looking to cast a custom view onto your cast-enabled device whether TV or chromecast, this is the way to go.